# MySQLdb can't use cursorclass

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
conn=MySQLdb.connect(host = '127.0.0.1',
                     user = 'root',
                     passwd = 'root',
                     db = 'test',
                     cursorclass = MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor=conn.cursor()
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 243, in cursor
  AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'cursorclass'
```

Why is this?

Comment: Your code works for me, but I find the path `build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg` strange - are you running the code out of a build directory?  Does the code work if you install, say, in a virtualenv?

Answer (score 13):

```py
 import MySQLdb
 import MySQLdb.cursors
 conn=MySQLdb.connect(host = '127.0.0.1',
                         user = 'root', 
                         passwd = 'root',
                         db = 'test',)
cursor=conn.cursor(cursorclass = MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

This is a rough hack, but it may not be advisable to use it. The script with throw out dictionary object by default but the application might require an tuple or array.